# How to apply global language filter across several fields in Sparql

Tags: sparql, semantic-web

I'm learning semantic web and using dbpedia to learn sparql. Below is an example to get all the schools in IL, USA. If you look at the filters, I'm filtering 2 fields (name and city) for the English language only.

Question - instead of 2 filter expressions or 'n' number of filter expressions per field, is it possible to set a global filter condition that can be applied to set of fields?

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

select ?link ?name ?city ?website where {
    SERVICE <https://dbpedia.org/sparql> {
        ?link rdf:type dbo:School .
        ?link rdfs:label ?name .
        ?link dbo:country dbr:United_States .
        ?link dbo:state dbr:Illinois . 
        ?link dbo:city ?city_link .
        ?city_link rdfs:label ?city .   
        OPTIONAL {
            ?link dbp:website ?website .
        }
        
    }
    FILTER (lang(?name)="en") .
    FILTER (lang(?city)="en") .
}
```

Comment: no it's not possible in standard SPARQL

Comment: Also note that you can use `langMatches` to match a language range (for English subtags).